# Yii: валидация массива

Tags: массивы, php, yii

Есть вьюха с чекбоксами

```
<?php print CHtml::activeCheckBoxList($listForm, 'id', CHtml::listData($units, 'id', 'name')); ?>
```

парвило валидации в модели формы

```
public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('id', 'required'),
            array('id', 'numerical'),
        );
    }
```

в контроллере всё это связано вот таким образом

```
    if (isset($_POST['listForm']))
    {
        $listForm->attributes = $_POST['listForm'];
        if ($listForm->validate())
        {
            //ещё код
        }
    }
```

И всё бы хорошо, но в 'id' на валидацию приходит не скалярное значение, а массив и выскакивает нотис:

```
Array to string conversion
```

Как валидировать массивы штатными средствами Yii?
Инет пока не помог, а костыли делать очень не хочется.

**Update**

В общем как и сказал [[@Алим](/users/13408/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC)](/users/13408/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC) без своего валидатора никак.

Всё сошлось на своём валидаторе.

```
public function existUnitId($attribute, $params)
{
    if (is_array($this->$attribute))
    {
        foreach ($this->$attribute as $atr)
        {
            //создаём экземпляр формы и присваиваем скалярное значение
            $listForm = new listForm;
            $listForm->id = $atr;

            //создаём валидатор
            $exist = CValidator::createValidator('exist', $listForm, $attribute, array('allowEmpty' => FALSE, 'className' => 'Unit', 'attributeName' => 'id'));
            $exist->validate($listForm, array($attribute));
            if ($listForm->hasErrors())
            {
                //добавляем ошибки
                $this->addErrors($listForm->getErrors());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а класс модели к $listForm указан?  
а чекбокс 1? может тогда сразу checkBox использовать?

Comment: 1. Уточнять лучше в комментариях.  
2. $listForm содержит экземпляр модели формы. Если бы его не было, не было б и чекбоксов :)

Comment: 1. учту, спасибо
2. уже понял не успел отредактировать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, кроме как `foreach` тут не обойтись, 
`activeCheckBoxList` так и должен возвращать массив

Спросил у Sam Dark (Александр Макаров)

> С валидацией в этом случае, наверное, только свой валидатор сделать. Ну или использовать `array('field', 'in', array(1,2,3,4,5))` в том случае когда есть список значений.

Comment: @Алим Просто трудно понять почему разработчики Yii не добавили такой функционал

Comment: я кажется ошибся http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515089/how-to-validate-checkbox-number-in-yii

Comment: @Алим там валидируется скалярное значение. Точнее про массив там ничего не сказано.

Comment: Всё сошлось на своём валидаторе. Добавил его в вопрос.